# Error while deploying Genexus App with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, genexus

Same Error occurred while deploying Genexus app with AWS Elastic beanstalk in Genexus 15, 16, 17.
Error Message:

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Start: Creating New Environment:
> **EnvironmentName** with Stack '64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.4.21 running Tomcat 8.5 Java 8'.  This will take some minutes in order to
> complete. .....waiting environment to be ready.... AWS is spinning up
> the infrastructure. Error： Environment **EnvironmentName** was
> destroyed. Please wait until Amazon completes the operation and retry
> later

I am using pro version for all of the 15, 16 and 17.
When I create Environment from AWS console directly, There is no error but, Error occurred while deploying from Genexus **Application Deploy** feature

I tried using different Genexus versions and also by changing the AWS Default Region too but, didn't work for me.